# JQuery for Terms & Conditions Dongle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to write some JQuery so that when I click the header 'Terms & Conditions' the actual terms themselves pop out from underneath the header or just reveal.

If you click on the header again, the terms hide.

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit of jQuery for this, alongside some CSS.

CSS:

```
#terms
{
    display: none; /*necessary*/
/*    otherstyles*/
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#header").click(function(){
    $("#terms").toggle();
});
```

This should now reveal the terms element when you click the header.

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxbgj/).

Answer (score 2):

You have to have your Terms on an absolute position of the page. And CSS them below your header.

CSS something like:

```
#termsdiv {
    display: none; /* Wil be shown by jQuery */
    position : absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%; /* CENTER the DIV */
    margin: 0 0 0 -400px; /* CENTER the DIV */
}
```

You javascript will look something like:

```
$("#header").click(function(){
    $("#termsdiv").toggle(); /* or use .fadeToggle() to use fades */
});
```

If you want to do it easy, without doing to much yourself. Try http://www.fancybox.net

Answer (score 1):

Soemthing along these lines should work for you:

```
$("#header").click(function() {
   $("#terms").toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
#terms { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will do with a fade-effect.

```
var isDisplay = false;
$('#T_&_C').bind('click', function() {
  if(isDisplay = false)
  {
    $('#id_content_div').fadeIn('slow');
    isDisplay = true;
  }
  else
  {
    $('#id_content_div').fadeOut('slow');
    isDisplay = false;
  }
});
```